# My program doesn't manipulate a string's values correctly

Tags: c

I need to code a program that gets input values for a string, then it ignores the characters that are not digits and it uses the digits from the string to create an integer and display it. [here are some strings turned into integers as stated in the exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5haL.png).

I wanted to go through the string as through a vector, then test if the each position is a digit using isdigit(s[i]), then put these values in another vector which creates a number using the digits. At the end it's supposed to output the number. I can't for the life of it figure what's wrong, please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *s;
    scanf("%s", s);
    printf("%s\n", s);

    int i, n=0, v[100], nr=0;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(s[i]) == 1)
        {
            v[i] = s[i];
            n++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", v[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        nr = nr * 10;
        nr = nr + v[i];
    }
    printf("%d", nr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think a little while: You have a pointer `s`, but where does it point?

Comment: You might also want to read an [ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii), the digits in your string (once you fix it) are not what you think they are. `'1' != 1`.

Comment: `v[i] = s[i];` should be `v[n] = s[i];` since you are pulling out numerals into another array.

Comment: did u stepo through the code with a debugger

Comment: first problem in the posted code: this line: `char *s;` is declaring a pointer, but not telling it where to point.  so this line: `scanf("%s", s);` is inputting characters into some random place in memory.  That is undefined behavior.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) where the format specifier `%s` is used,  Always use a 'max length' modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  2) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   Note: in the posted code, there is no input buffer declared, so trying to input anything using the `s` pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: Variable names should indicate usage or content (or better, both).  variable names like `s` convey nothing about the contents nor the usage

Comment: the function: `strlen()` returns type `size_t` (which is a unsigned long int) but is being assigned to a `int` variable.  'implicit conversion' will save the code, as long as the resulting value is >=0 and <=MAX_INT  Strongly suggest that the variable `i` have type: `size_t`

Comment: In C, when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )   The compiler puts out several warnings messages, amongst them is: "7:5: warning: 's' is used uninitialized in this function" and references this line: `scanf( "%s", s);`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanind: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a blank line.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when writing to `stdout` and/or `stderr`, always end the format string with '\n' so the output will be immediately displayed to the terminal.

Comment: regarding the first `for()` loop.  When some character is not a digit, the current character `v[i]` will not be set.  (so will contain garbage)  Suggest using a second index/offset variable/counter that tracks the current position in the array `v[]`.

Comment: remember that a `int` number cannot have more than (about) 14 digits, so if there were more than that number of digits in the input string, then the variable `nr` will overflow.   Also, a digit has a value in the range 0x30 ... 0x39 so it cannot be directly used in this line: `nr = nr + v[i];`  Rather use: `nr = nr + (v[i]-0x30);`

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `s` is unintialized which is your major problem. But there are other problems too.

- `isdigit()` is documented to return a non-zero return code which is not necessarily 1.
- The argument to `isdigit()` needs to be cast to `unsigned char` to avoid potential undefined behaviour.
- Your array `v` is also using the *same* index variable `i` - which is not right. Use a different variable to index `v` when you store the digits.
- You need to subtract `'0'` to get the each digits integer equivalent.
- `scanf()`'s format `%s` can't handle inputs with space (among other problems). So, use `fgets()`.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char s[256];
fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);
s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = 0; /* remove trailing newline if present */
printf("%s\n", s);

int i, n = 0, v[100], nr = 0;
size_t j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < s[i]; i++)
{
    if (isdigit((unsigned char)s[i]))
    {
        v[j++] = s[i];
        n++;
    }
}
for(i = 0;i < j; i++)
{
    printf("%c\n", v[i]);
}

if (j) { /* No digit was seen */
    int multiply = 1;
    for(i= j-1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
        nr = nr + (v[i] - '0') * multiply;
        multiply *= 10;
    }
}

printf("%d", nr);
return 0;
}
```

In addition be aware of integer overflow of `nr` (and/or `multiply`) can't hold if your input contains too many digits.

Another potential source of issue is that if you input over 100 digits then it'll overflow the array `v`, leading to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, I will make sure to use unsigned char in the future when I need to use isdigit or isspace, also counting i for v was a pretty fatal mistake too in my code. I didn't know that subtracting '0' from the digits gets the integer equivalent. I will also use fgets in the future, thanks again! I also initially defined true to 1 and I wasn't sure how booleans work in C ( I'm coming from C++ )

Comment: No problem. Any non-zero value is "true" in C. Besides, C does support bools. There's `<stdbool.h>` header since C99.

Comment: Your code generates a compiler warning "test.c(27): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch"

Comment: Sorry, I meant line 22, `for(i = 0;i < j; i++)`, and you have a very peculiar way of accumulating a value. The variable `multiply` is unnecessary. Multiply `nr` by `10` before the addition.

Comment: it works for me and it outputs the digits in order, probably some compiler bug

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help, i followed someone's advice and replaced
  v[i] = s[i] -> v[n] = s[i] and changed char *s with char s[100]
now it works perfectly, i got rid of the variable nr and just output the numbers without separating them through \n . Thanks for the debugger comment too, I didn't know I can use that effectively.

Comment: but your solution if far too complicated....you could resolve it just filtering the `isdigit()` chars, and the new lines.  You should get the same result, and for numbers with hundreds of digits :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you did not allocate any memory, I changed that to a fixed array.

Your use of `scanf` will stop at the first space (as in the first example input).

Next, you don't use the right array index when writing digits int `v[]`. However I have removed all that and simply used any digit that occurs.

You did not read the man page for `isdigit`. It *does not* return `1` for a digit. It returns **a nonzero value** so I removed the explicit test and left it as implicit for non-0 result.

I changed the string length and loop types to `size_t`, moving the multiple `strlen` calls ouside of the loop.

You have also not seen that digits' character values are not integer values, so I have subtracted `'0'` to make them so.

Lastly I changed the target type to `unsigned` since you will ignore any minus sign.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[100];                              // allocate memory
    unsigned nr = 0;                          // you never check a `-` sign
    size_t i, len;                            // correct types
    if(fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin) != NULL) {   // scanf stops at `space` in you example
        len = strlen(s);                      // outside of the loop
        for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if(isdigit(s[i])) {               // do not test specifically == 1 
                nr = nr * 10;
                nr = nr + s[i] - '0';         // character adjustment
            }
        }
        printf("%u\n", nr);                 // unsigned
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program session:

```
a2c3   8*5+=
2385
```

Comment: strlen() call is unnecessary when the zero terminator can be used. As I said in my answer, `isdigit()` call requires a cast.

Comment: Thank you for this code too, it's pretty straight forward and compact for an beginner like me, I just started using this site so I am not very familiar with choosing the right response so I apologize. Thank you for the additional comments too, they really help me understand what's going on on each line.

Comment: actually it looks like i need 15 reputation to upvote you, i will come back when i have 15 reputation and i'll upvote your response

Comment: ah you got the upvote actually but it's not publicly seen

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
        case '\n':
            putchar(c); break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
} /* main */
```

This is a sample execution:

```
$ pru_$$
aspj pjsd psajf pasdjfpaojfdapsjd 2 4 1
241
1089u 0u 309u1309u98u 093u82 40981u2 982u4 09832u4901u 409u 019u019u 0u3 0ue 
10890309130998093824098129824098324901409019019030
```

Very elegant! :)

Comment: thanks i apologize for not responding earlier i have just checked the thread in 2 weeks